# How to scrap all headings (h1-h6) of a full website using python?

Tags: python, web-scraping

I'm looking for a script that is able to collect **all headings** (h1-h6) of a **full website** by **main URL/domain** and export it in an **Excel/CSV** file.

I got a code that can collect only single-page headings.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url_link = "https://www.nypost.com"
request = requests.get(url_link)

Soup = BeautifulSoup(request.text, 'lxml')

heading_tags = ["h1", "h2", "h3"]
for tags in Soup.find_all(heading_tags):
    print(tags.name + ' -> ' + tags.text.strip())
```

Comment: At first, please check the terms of website. Also to get answers fit exactly your needs please focus, provide more details and expected output. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try something like

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url_link = "https://www.nypost.com"
request = requests.get(url_link)

Soup = BeautifulSoup(request.text, 'html.parser')

heading_tags = ["h1", "h2", "h3"]
for tags in Soup.find_all(heading_tags):
    print(tags.name + ' -> ' + tags.text.strip())
```

?

Something similar to that works for me in another project.

Comment: Yes, it is working for a single page, but I want to scrap the whole website headings.